# StackedView inside ScrollView in Xcode 8 / Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to arrange stacked views so I can set out the UI of my app to look neat and tidy.

The only problem I'm having at the minute is getting it set up so I can see it!

At the minute, it looks like this on Main.storyboard and it's annoying me:

[Storyboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8rie.png)

My constraints are currently set up as follows:

[Constraints (edited)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC1Nh.png)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: XCode has auto fix on storyboard, you could try that first.

Comment: I've tried that using "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" with no luck

Comment: The better way is understanding your constraints, and find out where the conflicts coming from. Since all your stackview is named StackView, I can barely see which constraint applies to which.

Comment: Apologies, I've edited it and now uploaded a correctly worded version of constraints

Comment: I have seen you have bunch of `UIView`, which does not have intrinsic size. You could try and apply some reasonable width and height for each `UIView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UIScrollView needs to know its content's width. Since it can scroll both horizontally and vertically, it does not act like a UIView on interface builder.

One thing you can do is adding a hidden UIView in UIScrollView with 0 height and `|-[WidthView]-|` constraints (leading and trailing to its superview - UIScrollView). And then you should add `WidthView.width = UIScrollView.superView.width` constraint.

This makes sure that your UIScrollView's contentView's width is always equals yo UIScrollView's superView's width.

Your view hierarchy should look like this:

[image: Your view hierarchy should look like this]